# codeigniter dropzone ajax upload with csrf

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csrf, dropzone.js

i'm using dropZone JS jquery plugin to upload images using codeigniter , in form there is a reset button for the form , when user upload image he can reset the form for new upload but after reset when upload  it show a message

> The action you have requested is not allowed.

by the way first upload success after that it fails with that message
note that i'm using the csrf protection

here is the init code for dropzone

```
 $(".dropzone").dropzone({
        url: "Images/up",
        maxFiles: 1,
        maxFilesize: 10, 
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        autoDiscover: false,
        params: {csrf_token: $.cookie("csrf_value")},
        init: function () {
            this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                $('#init_empty_msg').addClass('hidden');
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: is the csrf token passed correctly the sencond time too??

Comment: how to make sure that its refreshed or not ?!

Comment: If its not a page load it shouldn't change

Comment: i didnt understand , btw isnt params are each request excute $.cookie which mean retrive the current value even if it changed ?

Comment: Yes, But my doubt was if the csrf value from the cookie is available the second time or not? Just debug and see

Comment: i have bind on sending event and print the cookie its already updated , also i tried this code in sending event but same problem `on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
                        formData.append('csrf_token', $.cookie("csrf_value"));
                    })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $.ajaxPrefilter() before you all ajax and add to all your ajax in data option csrf token.
After this you make your ajax requests typicaly without declaration in data array csrf data
and

```
// for CI 3.0.4
data: {"<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>": "<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>"}
```